# Default Notification Settings according to Color in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

This is how I add my exams schedule in my Google Calendar:

1. Add an exam event/task in the proper time
2. Change the color to Red
3. (**Manually**) Change the notification settings to 3 hour before, 1 day before.
4. Repeat 1-3 for all exams

This is how I want to add my exams schedule in my Google Calendar:

1. Add an exam event/task at the proper time
2. Just set the color to red and the notifications **change by themselves** to 3 hour before, 1 day before
3. Repeat 1-2 for all exams

There is a setting that says I can change the notification for all event/tasks

[image: Settings to change notification for all tasks/events]

But I want to set this notification ( 3 hour and 1 day before ) for my exams only and not everything else.

Is this possible?